# Python Pubsub Subscriber client not pulling messages when filter is applied on subscription

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, publish-subscribe

I am using Pubsub streaming pull subscription in my Python web application. When I am not applying any subscription filter, the subscriber client is able to successfully pull messages from the subscription.
However, if a subscription filter is applied, the subscriber stops pulling messages.If I go manually to the specific subscription and click on 'Pull', I can see that there are messages in the subscription (which obviously matched the filter criteria and hence are present within subscription). But the client can not pull any of these messages.
Do I need to do any additional configuration for the client? The code for my subscriber client is as follows:-

```
import os

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from app.services.subscription_service import save_bill_events
from app.utils.constants import BILL_SUBSCRIPTION_GCP_PROJECT_ID, BILL_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from app.utils.logging_tracing_manager import get_logger



logger = get_logger(__file__)


def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    save_bill_events(message.data)
    message.ack()


subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(os.environ.get(BILL_SUBSCRIPTION_GCP_PROJECT_ID),
                                                 BILL_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

# Limit the subscriber to only have fixed number of  outstanding messages at a time.
flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=50)
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback, flow_control=flow_control)



async def poll_bill_subscription():
    
    with subscriber:
        try:
            # When `timeout` is not set, result() will block indefinitely,
            # unless an exception is encountered first.
           
            streaming_pull_future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            # Even in case of an exception, subscriber should keep listening
            logger.error(
                f"An error occurred while pulling message from subscription {BILL_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}",
                exc_info=True)
            
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My application was creating a subscriber client immediately after creating a subscription. When the subscription is created with a filter, it probably takes some time during which it does not register the subscriber client and does not throw any error also.
It works fine after a re-deployment. I added a small sleep and it works fine now